# JavaScript Revealing Module Pattern Variable Scope

Tags: javascript, revealing-module-pattern

I have an issue where I can't get to a variable inside a function:

**EDIT**
I forgot to add that I am setting this `workerPage.grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");` on the jQuery `$(function(){});`

I can't use `claimsGird` variable inside the save function, I have to referenec it by `workerPage.grid`. Not the other variables like `viewModel` work fine. Here is the snippet:

```
save = function () {
                saif.kendoGridUtils.addModifiedDataItems(
                    viewModel.CompanionClaims.Updated,
                    viewModel.CompanionClaims.Added,
                    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data()
                );

                $.ajax({
                    url: $("#contentForm").attr("action"),
                    data: JSON.stringify(viewModel),
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json"
                }).success(function (data) {
                    //syncs viewModel with changes in model
                    $.extend(viewModel, kendo.observable(data));

                    //rebinds the grid data source
                    claimsGrid.dataSource.data(viewModel.CompanionClaims.Rows);
```

Here is the full script:

```
var workerPage = (function () {
        var viewModel = kendo.observable(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))),
            claimsGrid = null,
            deleteFirm = function (firmModel) {
                firmModel.Name = "";
                firmModel.AttorneyName = "";
                firmModel.Address.Line1 = "";
                firmModel.Address.Line2 = "";
                firmModel.Address.City = "";
                firmModel.Address.State = "OR";
                firmModel.Address.ZipCode = "";
                firmModel.Address.PlusFourCode = "";
                firmModel.PhoneNumber = "";
                firmModel.FaxNumber = "";
                firmModel.ContactName = "";
            },
            bind = function () {
                kendo.bind($("#main-content"), viewModel);
            },
            save = function () {
                saif.kendoGridUtils.addModifiedDataItems(
                    viewModel.CompanionClaims.Updated,
                    viewModel.CompanionClaims.Added,
                    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data()
                );

                $.ajax({
                    url: $("#contentForm").attr("action"),
                    data: JSON.stringify(viewModel),
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json"
                }).success(function (data) {
                    //syncs viewModel with changes in model
                    $.extend(viewModel, kendo.observable(data));

                    //rebinds the grid data source
                    claimsGrid.dataSource.data(viewModel.CompanionClaims.Rows);


                    //rebinds view elements to view model so changes are visible
                    //kendo.bind($("#main-content"), viewModel);
                    bind();

                    // Errors and Warnings
                    var results = messageUtils.parseMessages(
                        viewModel.Messages.Errors,
                        viewModel.Messages.Informationals,
                        viewModel.Messages.Warnings
                    );

                    var errs = $("#errors").html(results.errorMessages);
                    $("#informationals").html(results.informationalMessages);
                    $("#warnings").html(results.warningMessages);

                    $.each(saif.kendoGridUtils.processErrors(viewModel.CompanionClaims.Rows), function (i, message) {
                        errs.html(errs.html() + message + "<br>");
                    });
                    // End Errors and Warnings

                });
            },
            deleteRow = function () {
                var row = claimsGrid.select(),
                    rowDataItem = claimsGrid.dataItem(row),
                    rowIndex = $(row).index(),
                    addedItemIndex = $.inArray(rowDataItem, viewModel.CompanionClaims.Added);

                //add to Deleted if not new
                if (addedItemIndex == -1 && $.inArray(rowDataItem, viewModel.CompanionClaims.Rows) != -1) {
                    viewModel.CompanionClaims.Deleted.push(rowDataItem);
                }

                //remove from Added if exists
                if (addedItemIndex != -1) {
                    viewModel.CompanionClaims.Added.splice(addedItemIndex, 1);
                }

                claimsGrid.removeRow(row);

                //select the next row, eg. if you delete row 2, select the row that took that rows poisition after it was deleted.
                claimsGrid.select(claimsGrid.tbody.find(">tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ")"));
            };

        return {
            bind: bind,
            deleteFirm: deleteFirm,
            deleteRow: deleteRow,
            grid: claimsGrid,
            save: save,
            viewModel: viewModel
        };

    }());
```

Comment: The only assignment to the `claimsGrid` variable is `claimsGrid = null`. Have you missed to show some of the code?

Comment: @nekman - Yes, please see my edit above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `claimsGrid` is never set to anything other than `null`. And setting `workerPage.grid` won't change the value of `claimsGrid` -- it's not a *pointer*, just a copy.

You'll instead have to use a getter/setter. With [newer browsers/engines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get#Browser_compatibility), that can be done with [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get) and [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/set):

```
// ...
return {
    // ...
    get grid() {
        return claimsGrid;
    },
    set grid(grid) {
        claimsGrid = grid;
    },
    // ...
};
```

You can also define `grid` as a function:

```
// ...
function getOrSetGrid(grid) {
    if (typeof newGrid === 'undefined') {
        return claimsGrid;
    } else {
        claimsGrid = grid;
    }
}

return {
    // ...,
    grid: getOrSetGrid,
    // ...
};
// ...
```

```
// rather than: workerPage.grid = ...;
workerPage.grid(...);
```

Or split it into `getGrid` and `setGrid` functions.

Comment: I forgot to add that I am setting this `workerPage.grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");` on the jQuery `$(function(){});`

Comment: @SamStriano Since you were including `claimsGrid` in the "*reveal*," I assumed that was the case. But, as I noted, setting `workerPage.grid` won't affect `claimsGrid` -- "*it's not a pointer, just a copy.*"

Comment: Could you elaborate on "it's not a pointer, just a copy"? Maybe a link somewhere that explains this a little better? Thanks!!

Comment: @SamStriano `workerPage.grid` doesn't have any ties back to `claimsGrid` beyond being the source of its initial value (the *copy*). It doesn't hold a reference to `claimsGrid` in any way (as a *pointer* would). They are instead entirely separate variables that just so happen to have the same value for a time. But, setting one to a new value won't be reflected in the other since they are separate.

Answer (score 0):

Scope in javascript works differently than other languages like Java or C#.  In your case claimsGrid is not in scope for the save function.  Does this help? http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/